# How allow protocol upgrade from http1.1 to http2 in curl?

Tags: http, curl

For debugging purposes I wan't to use curl. My Webserver is able to handle HTTP\1.1 Requests in two different ways:

1. If Client allows Upgrade he uses HTTP\2
2. If not he uses HTTP\1.1

So the question is how to use curl and set upgrade to HTTP\2 as allowed.

Using:

```
curl --http2 --data "test" localhost:80
```

doesn't fit my needs. I need something like:

```
curl --http1.1 --data "test" (Allow upgrade to http/2) localhost:80
```

Thanks for your answers.

Regards